# Global variable in query php/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

I have a website with 3 dropdown menus that loop through a database in mysql to get 50 bands in a list you can chose. I have made it so if you vote for band number 1, he gets 10 points, number 2, 6 points etc.. Now i have the problem that you can vote for 3 the same bands bcs those dropdown are each looping trough the database. I want to make a global variable so i can put in the query from dropdown 1 of 2 that it doesnt show the chose in dropdown 1.. so like "WHERE NOT LIKE *'variable'*" 
Here is my code for dropdown 1:

```
<?php echo '<select name="bands1">';
      echo '<option>Kies een band</option>';

$sql="SELECT * FROM bands ORDER BY band"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql);


if (!$result){
      die ("Database connection failed!");
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo '<option value="' . $row['BandID'] . '">' . $row['band'] . '</option>'; 

}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

this is for the 2 other dropdown menus the same only the select name is different

this is my connection file that i included at the top of the html file:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST',  'localhost');
define('DB_USER',  'root');
define('DB_PASS',  '');
define('DB_NAME',  'mysql_enquete');

$db_link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die ("Verbindingsfout");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
?>
```

Somebody on stackoverflow that can help me?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem but i want help with something i want to add in my project.. i have 3 dropdowns menus that loop through a table in my database.. but you can choose 3 times the same band in the dropdown menus... so you have for example 3 times "Linkin park" but i want with a global variable to remove it when you have already chose it in the second dropdown menu and than the third too... but im stuck how to figure it out.. already found this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php here i found something about this but this is the old php code.. with mysql_query and i use myqli